# windows_package resource is demanding the source parameter

Tags: windows, windows-installer, chef-infra, chef-recipe, cookbook

According to the [chef doc](https://docs.chef.io/resource_windows_package.html) the source param is optional and:

> ...If the source property is not specified, the package name MUST be
>   exactly the same as the display name...

I confirmed the package is correct (including case) in add remove programs and the registry and did this in my recipe:

```
windows_package 'My Package Name' do
  action :remove
end
```

Yet it throws this error:

```
    ================================================================================
Error executing action `remove` on resource 'windows_package[My Package Name]'
           ================================================================================

Chef::Exceptions::ValidationFailed
----------------------------------
source is required
```

Source is required? No its not! Is the documentation wrong or am I just being dumb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Known issue, you can follow it at https://github.com/chef/chef/issues/5274.